# select 要素の値が他のスクリプトによって変更された場合にイベントを受け取りたい

Tags: javascript, jquery

お世話になってます
初心者ですがなにとぞよろしくお願いします。

`<select>` 要素の値が変わったことをトリガーに見栄えが変わるjQueryのプラグインを作成中です。

`<select>` の選択が「他のスクリプト」によって変更されたときにjQueryでそのイベントを取得したいと考えています。「他のスクリプト」は不特定です。

jQueryにおいて

```
$('select').change(myFnc);
```

ですがスクリプトによる操作では、myFncは呼び出されません。
（スクリプトによる変更は発火しない、と解釈しています）。

「他のスクリプト」で値が変更された場合にもイベントをとりたいので、

```
$('select').val('hoge').trigger('change');
```

としたいところですが、当然「他のスクリプト」は不特定なのでそれはできません。

なにとぞアドバイスをお願いします。

Comment: 「スクリプトによる変更がイベントを起こさない」のであれば「(スクリプトからの変更の)イベントを取りたい」は矛盾しています。値を変更する側でイベントを起こす必要があると思います。あるいはイベントを起こすようなメソッド・関数を変更する側は使用するように強制する必要があると思います。もしくはやりたくないけどポーリングするとか・？。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
具体的には、SELECTの選択によって動作するjQueryプラグインなのですが、
Anguler.js によってSELECTの選択が変わった場合の拾い方に難儀してるカンジです。

たしかに、発生しないイベントは取得しようがないですねw。

Javascriotの仕様に詳しくないので、
もしかしたら、jQueryで拾えないだけで、何か変化を感知できる方法があるのかなぁ、と思った次第です。

Comment: 私も仕様にそれほど詳しいわけではないのではっきりは言えないですが、「スクリプトからの変更はイベントを起こさない」のは実際に確かめられますからイベントとしては収得できないですね。（それは多分、スクリプトからの変更ならば変更したものがイベントを起こせ（スクリプトからイベントを発火できるから）という方針なのだろうと思います）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

かなり強引ですが、`setTimeout`を使えば擬似的な`change`トリガを作れます。

ただ、`select`を選択中(確定前)にも値が変わってしまいます。
この動作が許容できれば`.val()`で値取得していれば良いと思います。

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    checkSelect();
});

var selectValue = 1;
function checkSelect(){

    if(selectValue != $("select").val()){
        // changeイベントと同等
        $("div").text($("select").val());
    }

    selectValue = $("select").val();

    // 250msec後に再チェック
    setTimeout(function(){checkSelect();}, 250);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>

<select>
    <option value="1" selected>aaa</option>
    <option value="2">bbb</option>
    <option value="3">ccc</option>
</select>
```

Comment: これが一番馴染みやすいやり方ではありますよねぇ

Answer (score 2):

いろんな意味で良くない方法だと思いますが…  
スクリプトでselectedを設定すると仮定してこれって出来るかな？

```
function sss(a,b){ //値変更時用
  delete a.selected;
  a.selected = b;
  a.__defineSetter__("selected", function(y) { 
  alert('chenge!');//実行したいfunction
  sss(a,y) });
}

//個別にoptionタグにsetterを設定
var xxx = document.getElementsByTagName('option')[0];
xxx.__defineSetter__("selected", function(y) { 
  alert('chenge!');//実行したいfunction
  sss(xxx,y); });
```

※適当に書いたコードです。  
※__defineSetter__は非推奨です。

---

** 2015/03/12 追記**

少し調べて書いてみました。

「他のスクリプト」によってプロパティに代入される時に  
発火するイベント自体を作ってしまうという発想です。

set/getを使った方が良いかもしれませんね。  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592753/how-to-define-setter-getter-on-prototype

```js
var useSetter = true;

//emulate legacy getter/setter API using ES5 APIs より抜粋
//http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/09/07/transitioning-existing-code-to-the-es5-getter-setter-apis.aspx
try {
   if (!Object.prototype.__defineGetter__ &&
    Object.defineProperty({},"x",{get: function(){return true}}).x) {
  Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "__defineGetter__",
     {enumerable: false, configurable: true,
      value: function(name,func)
         {Object.defineProperty(this,name,
             {get:func,enumerable: true,configurable: true});
  }});
  Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "__defineSetter__",
     {enumerable: false, configurable: true,
      value: function(name,func)
         {Object.defineProperty(this,name,
             {set:func,enumerable: true,configurable: true});
  }});
   }
} catch(defPropException) {
 alert(' "__defineGetter__" & "defineProperty" 非対応です。');
 useSetter = false;
/*Do nothing if an exception occurs*/
};


if (useSetter){//初期設定
 var opts = document.getElementsByTagName('option');
 for (var i = 0; i < opts.length;i++) {
   (function (i) {
 opts[i].__defineSetter__('selected', function (y) {
   alert('chenge! :'+i); //実行したいfunction
   seta_sel(opts[i], y);
 });
   })(i);
 }
}

function seta_sel(a,b){ //値変更時の処理
  delete a.selected; // 自身が代入の邪魔をするのでselectedを消して作り直す
  a.selected = b;
  a.__defineSetter__("selected", function(y) {  //setterを設定 
  alert('chenge! :'+(a.value-1));//実行したいfunction
  seta_sel(a,y) });
}

//選択変更スクリプト
function check(x){
 var opts = document.getElementsByTagName('option')[x-1].selected=true;
}

function check2(x){ //jquery版
  $("select#sel1").val(x);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>

<select id="sel1" name="seln1">
    <option value="1" selected>aaa</option>
    <option value="2">bbb</option>
    <option value="3">ccc</option>
</select>

<br><input type="button" onclick="check('1');" value="リストaaaを選択">
<br><input type="button" onclick="check('2');" value="リストbbbを選択">
<br><input type="button" onclick="check('3');" value="リストcccを選択">

<br>jqueryだと他のoptionを初期化するからそれも発火してしまいます…
<br><input type="button" onclick="check2('3');" value="リストcccをjqueryで選択">
```

もっとスマートに出来る方法無いかしら…

Comment: おお、面白いですね。
ちょっと研究してみます